# Help importing a biom file into R

Tags: r

How can I import a biom file?

When I run the following code:

```
library(phyloseq)
import_biom(
    "/Users/name/Dropbox/*****.biom", 
    parseFunction=parse_taxonomy_greengenes, 
    parallel=F)
```

I get the following error message:

> biom either as JSON (BIOM-v1) or HDF5 (BIOM-v2). Check file path, file
> name, file itself, then try agai

Comment: what happens when you do ``file.exists("/Users/name/Dropbox/*****.bio")``

Comment: you can check with `file *****.biom` as well, to check if your biom file is text or HDF5-like file, to distinguish between versions 1 and 2.

Comment: The relevant package for `import_biom` should be added to your code (e.g. `library(phyloseq)`).

Comment: Thank you.    file.exists("/Users/name/Dropbox/*****.bio")  [1] TRUE

Comment: > to check if your biom file is text or HDF5-like file, to distinguish between versions 1 and 2.
How can I check? If it is version 1, what should I do and if it is version 2, what should I do?

Comment: Biological Observation Matrix 1.0.0, so I think this is JSON file.